# How to send multiple arguments to a python through subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I have two python files located in different directories.

```
folder1
    |--> routing.py
folder2
    |--> script.py
```

I want to execute `script.py` from `routing.py`. `script.py` takes multiple parameters to run. Currently, I am using `subprocess` module python.

**routing.py**

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def test():
    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(folder2_path)
    output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "script.py", param1, param2, param3 ])
```

but, I am getting

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
```

Is there any better way to do this? Do I miss something?

Comment: In general you need not `chdir` to the directory (this means influencing your own process more than you typically want) because you can simply give the working directory to the call of `check_output()`.

Comment: Can you re-work your `script.py` file so that you import it and call the function you want to run?

Comment: `check_output` is *supposed* to throw an error if the subprocess fails. You want to avoid calling Python as a subprocess of Python anyway. See further https://stackoverflow.com/a/51950538/874188

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me

```
python1.py

import sys
global var
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]

var = int(arg1) + int(arg2)
print var
```

and the next file is

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def test():
    dirpath = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir('.')
    output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "python1.py", '3', '3' ])
    print "output: ",output

test()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your code here.  Here is a hopefully minimal fix:

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def test():
    return subprocess.check_output([
        os.path.join(['folder1', sys.executable], 
        os.path.join(['folder2', "script.py"],
        param1, param2, param3 ])
```

A much better solution is to refactor `script.py` so that you can `import` it from your current script.  This is also brittle in the sense that it requires the current directory to be the directory of the current script.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the script from a different folder. Try with `../folder2/script.py` as an argument to check_output, or, if the other script contains relative/non-absolute paths too, consider rewriting it so that you can import methods and classes from it instead of trying to execute it externally.